# ¿Cómo puedo serializar o numerar filas de una tabla?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla que contiene múltiples campos con diversos valores entre los cuales tengo uno que me numera de acuerdo a múltiples razones. Ej.:

```
Table  
Id|Numeracion|  
1|NULL  
2|1  
3|NULL  
4|4
```

Lo que yo requiero es rellenar los valores `null` (solo en la consulta, la tabla no debe ser modificada) con los números intermedios disponibles (2 y 3 en este caso) o en caso de que no hubiera intermedios continúe la numeración con el siguiente numero inmediato al existente.

Ej Resultado deseado:

```
Table  
Id|Numeracion|  
1|2  
2|1  
3|3  
4|4
```

Ejemplo Datos 2:

```
Table  
Id|Numeracion|  
1|2  
2|1  
3|NULL  
4|NULL
```

Resultado deseado en Ejemplo 2:

```
Table  
Id|Numeracion|  
1|2  
2|1  
3|3  
4|4
```

Comment: Basado en tu ejemplo, que pasaría si la columna `numeración` del Id con valor `4` es nulo ¿Qué valores de numeración debe considerar? ¿Qué valor debe ser el rango mínimo y máximo para ser considerados como números intermedios?. Podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar otros casos.

Comment: He modificado la pregunta. gracias por responder.

Comment: De igual forma, me gustaría saber como puedo lograr eso pero obteniendo los valores para rellenar de otra tabla.

Comment: Te falto añadir en que tipo de base de datos.

Comment: Gracias, agregado! Microsoft SQL Server (.mdb)

Comment: ¿La columna `Id` siempre será consecutivo?. Considerando tu ejemplo, ¿Se podría decir que `1` será el mínimo y máximo `4` para considerarlo en tu columna `numeracion`?

Comment: `Id` siempre será consecutivo, sin embargo al eliminar un registro queda ese "hueco" por ello quiero numerarlo con otro método. Siempre debe existir el minimo `1` y el máximo debe ser el total de registros obtenidos al ejecutar la consulta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siendo `Tabla` el nombre de tu tabla, podrías usar expresión de tabla comunes:

```
;WITH CONSECUTIVO
AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Numeracion
                                 ,id
                             ) [Indice]
       ,id
       ,Numeracion
    FROM Tabla
   )
,NUMERACION_VALIDO
AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Indice) [Identificador]
       ,Indice
    FROM CONSECUTIVO C
    WHERE Indice NOT IN (
                            SELECT Numeracion
                            FROM Tabla
                            WHERE Numeracion IS NOT NULL
                        )
   )
SELECT CON.id
   ,NV.Indice
FROM NUMERACION_VALIDO NV
    INNER JOIN CONSECUTIVO CON
        ON CON.Indice = NV.Identificador
UNION
SELECT id
   ,Numeracion
FROM dbo.Tabla
WHERE Numeracion IS NOT NULL;
```

Obtendrás:

> ```
> +----+--------+
> | id | Indice |
> +----+--------+
> |  1 |      2 |
> |  2 |      1 |
> |  3 |      3 |
> |  4 |      4 |
> +----+--------+
> ```

[**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/SECTP99591)

---

**Referencia:**

- [WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql)

Comment: gracias. revisaré la consulta y te cuento como me va. No se si me pudieras ayudar a realizar lo mismo sólo que la numeración la obtengamos de una tabla y la relacionemos con un `Id` Muchas Gracias

Comment: Gracias, Davlio me funcionó de 100. Muchas gracias por el DEMO.